# Clicking on point to have additional points and geographical information show up in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am mapping nonprofits in Costa Rica, using the headquarters as the main points on the map. I want end users to be able to click on the points and see additional information about each individual nonprofit like zone of impact (polygon), project locations (points) and additional offices (points).

To do this using QGIS, would I have to make a layer for each nonprofit?

[image: My map thus far]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into layer-properties --> actions, create default to see what options there is.[image: quickscreengrab]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting up an data-defined visibility depending on the `is_selected` function.

The end user will click on a non-profit point using the Select Features tool. All of the symbology that you set up will appear for that feature.

Say you have a second layer with "zone of impact" polygons.

This layer should have a shared attribute with the nonprofit point layer. This attribute can be the nonprofit's name, or a unique ID number. For example, if the non-profit is named "Shirts for Sloths", there should be a polygon in the zone of impact layer that also has the name "Shirts for Sloths."

Add a geometry generator style layer to your nonprofit headquarters layer. Choose "polygon" as the geometry type, and use this expression:

```
if(is_selected(),geometry(get_feature('Zone of Influence','Name',"Name")),null)
```

Substitute the appropriate values from your data for the following terms:

- `'Name'` is the shared ID field in the Zone of Influence layer
- `"Name"` is the shared ID field in the nonprofit headquarters layer
- `'Zone of Influence'` is the name of the influence zone layer

The geometry generator layer will display the zone of influence polygon for any nonprofit headquarter point the user selects.

Here, the headquarters of the nonprofit Watershed Restoration Group is selected:

[image]

Here, the headquarters of Shirts for Sloths is selected:

[image]

Create additional geometry generator symbology layers for each additional set of information you want to display (project locations, additional offices, etc.).

Of course the downside with this method is that the feature will always be whatever color is set for selected features (by default it's yellow). If you add multiple symbol layers, this will get confusing because they will all be yellow.

Theoretically, you could apply a data-defined visibility setting to other layers based on whether the matching symbol in the nonprofit HQ layer is selected. I couldn't get that to work, though.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the information it seems to be exactly what I want, but I am having trouble actually implementing it. I have tried implementing it in many ways and i still cant get it to appear when clicked on

Comment: Did you substitute the name of the zone layer where my example says `'Zone of Influence'`?

Comment: Hello, yes. His is a description of hwat I have tried:
-I have gone to the layer styling section of my "nonprofit hq" layer
- the symbology is currently set to catagories, so I added a new category (zona de impacto) 
-I selected geometry generator and added this code: if(is_selected(),geometry(get_feature('Zona de Impacto','apodo',"apodo")),null)
- Zona de Impacto- is the layer with the geometries, "apodo" is the shared attribute between them.
- from there when i try and click and identify nonprofits in the map, nothing happens.

Comment: Potential problems: in the "zona de impacto" layer, the only attribute available in the attribute table is "apodo", no geospacial info. When I bring it up in the expression diologue the output preview is always "null"

Comment: You have to *select* the point feature in "nonprofit hq". Attribute tables don't usually have geospatial information; that information is displayed on the map. If the zona de impacto layer doesn't have geometry, of course it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your continued guidance, I am new to Qgis so all this information is very helpful. The "zona de impacto" layer is an ESRI shapefile with polygons mapped out on it. Unfortunately, the problem still persists even after I used the selection tool rather than the identify tool... I am unsure how to continue, but it is very frustrating